# ActionController::RoutingError - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have this route:

rake routes:

```
channel_import GET    /channels/:channel_id/import(.:format)    channels#import
```

but when I try to use it in a link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Import", channel_import_path(:hit_id => index), :method=>:get %>
```

I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"import", :controller=>"channels", :hit_id=>0}):
```

this is the path which I add in routes.rb:

```
resources :channels do
    get 'import' => 'channels#import'
end
```

This is my controller:

```
class ChannelsController < ApplicationController
  def import
    puts "import action"
    head :ok
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Should this action be in context of a specific channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to pass `channel_id` in the link params, something like

```
<%= link_to "Import", channel_import_path(:hit_id => index, :channel_id => @channel.id), :method=>:get %>
```

For above output path will be something like `/channels/21/import?hit_id=12`

Answer (score 1):

You set `:hit_id` param in your link, while your route requires `:channel_id`. This should work:

```
<%= link_to "Import", channel_import_path(channel_id: 'your_channel_id') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you're using `hit_id`, it should be `channel_id`:

```
<%= link_to "Import", channel_import_path(:channel_id => index) %>
```

When you have [routes with params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), you have to pass the param as described in the routes file. So with your route as below, you need to send the `channel_id` param

```
channel_import GET    /channels/:channel_id/import(.:format)    channels#import
```

Something you may benefit from is the ability to send params, or not. This can be achieved with brackets:

```
channel_import GET    /channels(/:channel_id)/import(.:format)    channels#import
```